# Serverless framework - Lambda function with Authorizer COGNITO_USER_POOLS always return "Unauthorized"

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, unauthorized

I can't figure out what's wrong on my Authorization.

I've a Hello function which only returns a simple a static message. If I deploy without set "Authorizer", it works. I've tested on Postman. The issue starts when I try adding Authorizer.

I've my Cognito fully working. On my front end I can sign up, then do a login and then get the Token from this login session.

When I go to Postman and test, I'm always getting "unauthorized" as answers.
On Postman I test on GET method, on "Headers" tab I added "Authorization" attribute and pasted on value the token that I've from Login session. I also tested this on the value field the prefix "bearer" as some places recommended. No success.

[image]

I've been trying for the past week solve this issue. Please, any help will be extremely useful.

`serverless.yml`

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1
  environment: 
    MY_TABLE: ${self:custom.myStage}_${self:custom.settings.tb_items}
    MY_STAGE: ${self:custom.myStage}
    MY_DOMAIN: ${self:custom.myDomain}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "dynamodb:GetItem"
        - "dynamodb:PutItem"
        - "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
        - "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
        - "dynamodb:Scan"
      Resource: "*"

functions:
  hello:
    handler: ${self:custom.pathFunc}/phraseOption.hello
    events:
      - http: 
          method: GET 
          path: hello
          cors: true
          integration: lambda-proxy
          authorizer:
            type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
            authorizerId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayAuthorizer

resources:
  Resources:
    CognitoUserPool:
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        MfaConfiguration: OFF
        UserPoolName: ${self:custom.myStage}_aePool
        EmailVerificationSubject: 'Your verification Code'
        EmailVerificationMessage: 'Use this code to confirm your sign up {####}'
        AutoVerifiedAttributes:
          - email
        UsernameAttributes:
          - email
        Policies:
          PasswordPolicy:
            MinimumLength: 6
            RequireLowercase: False
            RequireNumbers: False
            RequireSymbols: False
            RequireUppercase: False
    CognitoUserPoolClient:
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient"
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        ClientName: ${self:custom.myStage}_aePoolClient
        GenerateSecret: False
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPool
    ApiGatewayAuthorizer: 
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties: 
        Name: CognitoUserPool
        Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
        IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
        RestApiId: 
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        ProviderARNs: 
          - Fn::GetAtt:
              - CognitoUserPool
              - Arn
```

`phraseOptions.js`

```
module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Your function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    }),
  };

  callback(null, response);
};
```

`I can see the function was created with the correct Auth:`

[image]

`Also Authorizer create as expected (I guess)`

[image]

`Swagger`

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "2019-10-07T21:24:17Z"
  title: "XXXXXX"
host: "XXXXXX"
basePath: "/dev"
schemes:
- "https"
paths:
  /getPhrase:
    get:
      responses: {}
    options:
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: "string"
  /hello:
    get:
      responses: {}
      security:
      - CognitoUserPool: []
  /item:
    post:
      responses: {}
    options:
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: "string"
  /item/{itemId}:
    get:
      responses: {}
    put:
      responses: {}
    delete:
      responses: {}
    options:
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: "string"
  /items:
    get:
      responses: {}
    options:
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: "string"
securityDefinitions:
  CognitoUserPool:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "Authorization"
    in: "header"
    x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: "cognito_user_pools"
```

Comment: can you share the swagger file also?

Comment: I'm very new with Serverless, ok? As far I can tell, I'm not using any Swagger file.

Comment: Ok, no worries. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html at the bottom

Comment: Done. I just added it. Thanks for also saying how to provide this information =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figure out what was wrong!

The server side was Ok. The issue on testing it on Postman was the Token.
I was using "cognitoUser.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken", but supposed to be "cognitoUser.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken".

Everything working as expected now.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more than once, I've been spending hours banging my head against the exact same problem